# Can Renderscript code be compiled to and run on Snapdragon's Haxagon DSP?

Tags: android, signal-processing, renderscript, hexagon-dsp

Renderscript is claimed to support "different types of processors such as the CPU, GPU or DSP." Now, probably the most popular DSP these days in the Android world is [Hexagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualcomm_Hexagon) present in Snapdragon SOCs. Can Renderscript code be made to run on Hexagon at all? If so, how to do it and what are the limitations?

**UPDATE**

regarding my hitherto investigation of the issue - there is no documentation nor examples available, so reverse engineering Qualcomm drivers seems like logical next step. For obvious reasons, I thought I'd ask first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't force RenderScript to run on any particular processor, so there is really nothing you can do here (unless you are going to write a Hexagon compiler + driver). As far as the existence of a Hexagon driver/compiler, none of the Nexus devices currently ship with Hexagon support for RenderScript, although each of them does have GPU support for RenderScript.

Comment: Assuming there was a driver like that, is Renderscript architecturally capable of running kernels on distinct hardware concurrently? That is, assuming there are no data dependecies, could I have one kernel running on GPU, while the next one would start execution on Hexagon? (And then another on the CPU?)

Comment: We don't have a way to do concurrent kernels yet, but you could certainly split a kernel across multiple devices for execution (i.e. execute 1/3 on CPU, 1/3 on GPU, 1/3 on DSP).

Answer (score 0):

How RenderScript split a kernel across multiple devices? Is always equals to the devices? (i.e. In nexus 5 execute 1/2 on CPU and 1/2 on GPU?).

Comment: This should really be a comment not an answer

Comment: It is up to the specific driver for a given device to determine how to partition work (CPU, GPU, etc.). It might be static (i.e. always execute kernels on the GPU if you can), or dynamic (i.e. the GPU is overloaded with other work, so execute on the CPU this time).

Comment: The GPU drive decides work partition? (i.e. in Nexus 5, the kernel is sent to GPU and Adreno drive decides how much execute?) My question is who (Renderscript, Adreno drive) divides workload?

Comment: It isn't just the GPU driver. The vendor's driver makes these decisions. Right now, I don't think any of them actually split work, and instead make all-or-nothing decisions on CPU vs. GPU. That said, the framework is there to actually split work, but just hasn't been used yet.